# Are you supposed to know who you're playing as in Metal Gear Solid 3?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-3-snake-eater, metal-gear-solid-series

In *Metal Gear Solid 3*, are you supposed to know that you are playing as "Big Boss" and not Solid Snake?

I haven't played *MGS3* in quite a while, and actually never completed the game, but was just wondering if it is supposed to be obvious you are playing as Big Boss and not younger Solid Snake.

Since I didn't finish the game, I didn't really figure it out until I played *MGS4*, but I was just wondering if it was obvious in *MGS3* if you played long enough or something.

Note: I played and finished the original *MGS1*, *MGS2*, and *MGS4*, but for some reason I always lost my enthusiasm for *MGS3* before I could complete the game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are immediately supposed to know you are not playing as Solid Snake. The game takes place in 1964; *Metal Gear* takes place in 1995 and stars Solid Snake, who looks the same age as (or younger than) Snake in *MGS3*.

If you have played *MGS1* / *MGS2*, you know Solid Snake is a clone of Big Boss. Well, here's a game where you play a character who looks exactly like Solid Snake, 30 years earlier, and has the codename "Snake". Who could that be?

As someone paying attention to gaming news when MGS3 was being previewed, Kojima was coy during interviews, but "everyone" knew that this game starred Big Boss before it came out.

Comment: How do you know it took place in 1964?  Again, I haven't played in a while.  For all I know, there was text at the bottom of the screen during the intro saying "1964".  I knew it was a ways in the past, but I didn't really know how long...

Comment: "How do you know it took place in 1964?" Well, it's in the manual, on the box, on a bunch of the advertising, it's one of the first bits of text shown in the game, Snake is doing "the first HALO jump" which in the real world occurred in the early 1960s, your first task is rescuing the scientist supposedly responsible for the Vostok 1... I have no idea how you _missed_ the fact the game occurred in the early 1960s.

Comment: should point at that at the very end "Naked Snake" is given the new name/rank of "Big Boss" having killed "The Boss", with the eye patch it like saying _now we name this guy who looks like Solid Snake and as an eye patch "Big Boss"_

Comment: "How do you know it took place in 1964?"
The Intro, Snake "After the end of WWII the World was split into two, east and west, this marked the begining of the era called the Cold War;
The weapons;
The music
The Clothes
The Tech